# How to show finishing form in Setup Wizard as if setup was interrupted?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, setup-project, wizard

I am creating a setup wizard project in Visual Studio 2010. During the installation I am running a PowerShell script in a custom action and depending on its result I need to show a successful or interrupted/failed finishing form. How can I do that?

PS The script is running in a silent mode if it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard setup wizard doesn't support statuses. The only way to interrupt setup programmatically is to throw exception which causes a notification, what is not acceptable in my case.